# Error with save! method in Rails 3.1.0-rc6

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Dont know what I am doing wrong...
Have this code:

```
new_model = Model.new(:brand_id=>brand_id, :name=>new_model_name)
new_model.save!
ModelImage.upload(new_model.id, params[:images])
```

but new_model.id equals to nil. WTF?

Tried in rails c, no errors. SQl is OK.

Thx.

Some code from Rails Console:

```
irb(main):045:0> h = Model.create(:brand_id=>2, :name=>'SKyFy')
SQL (0.1ms)  BEGIN
SQL (42.2ms)  INSERT INTO `models` (`brand_id`, `id`, `name`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)     [["brand_id", 2], ["id", nil], ["name", "SKyFy"]]
(118.7ms)  COMMIT
=> #<Model id: nil, brand_id: 2, name: "SKyFy">
irb(main):046:0> h.id
=> nil
```

Dont have any attr_*, validations. Models are clear.

Another example:

```
irb(main):048:0> h = Model.new(:brand_id=>1, :name=>'SKYDOS')
=> #<Model id: nil, brand_id: 1, name: "SKYDOS">
irb(main):049:0> h.save!
SQL (0.2ms)  BEGIN
SQL (3.4ms)  INSERT INTO `models` (`brand_id`, `id`, `name`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["brand_id", 1], ["id", nil], ["name", "SKYDOS"]]
(83.5ms)  COMMIT
=> true
irb(main):050:0> h.id
=> nil
irb(main):051:0> h.errors
=> #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x9a37c18 @base=#<Model id: nil, brand_id: 1, name: "SKYDOS">,     @messages={}>
irb(main):052:0>
```

PS
*Solved my problem*... had TWO primary keys.
Thx to all.

Comment: I think I've had a similar problem, can you show me your schema.rb?

Comment: I am not using migrations in this project. DB schema was created in MySQL Workbench.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set

```
config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```

in config/application.rb

this should hopefully solve your problems.

Note the query,

```
INSERT INTO `models` (`brand_id`, `id`, `name`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["brand_id", 1], ["id", nil], ["name", "SKYDOS"]
```

This query is wrong, Rails doesn't know about the primary key of the table and assumes (incorrectly) that id is just a normal column. With an SQL schema format - this should work fine.

You can confirm this by looking at db/schema.rb and you will end up with something like:

```
create_table "foos", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "id",                                 :null => false
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say with so little information, but the answer most likely lies in your validations for `new_model`.

Have a look at `new_model.rb` and see if there are any validations that may be failing.

If not, see if you have an `attr_accessible`/`attr_protected` conflict.

To help you find the answer quickly, add the line:

```
logger.debug new_model.errors
```

after your `save!` and you'll see what's going on in your logs.

Comment: What do you have going on in `new_model.rb`?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have primary key 'id' with **auto_increment** in model's table.